# Are snails on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Please advise.

Are snails on topic?

---

*aka are snails on the menu?*

Answer (score 16):

Sure. Pet snails are pets, and therefore on topic.

A question about what to do with garden snails as pests would not be on topic.

Comment: People have snails as pets?

Comment: Yes. Presumably the OP of the linked question does, unless by "I have many snails" they're talking about raising them to eat them.

Comment: Snails are commonly included in aquariums to help keep algae levels down, so yes, pet snails are not uncommon.

Answer (score 9):

I think they should be.

There is going to be a lonnnng continuum of "pets" running the gambit from dogs and cats, to birds, reptiles, amphibians, fish… right on through to things like arachnids and snails.

At this stage, I *don't* think we should harass people too much over the *according-to-Hoyle* definition of a "pet." Definitions will vary by culture, and frankly I don't see these these less conventional interests detracting from the mainstream-companion questions you find on every other site on this subject.

Generally speaking, I think it's okay to keep it simply stated: **"This site welcomes questions by individuals generally seeking to provide personal care of an animal in a domestic setting."** That's in contrast to, say, industrial methods for rearing of animals for agricultural use, or zoological veterinary issues, or getting rid of pests in your garden.

I think if we take a lighter approach to moderation of these questions, you'll know when the questions start to fall well beyond the expertise we've gathered here. Until then, just enjoy.